# Add new columns to a dataframe in for loop

Tags: python, for-loop

I am able to write a for loop that adds a row to a dataframe each time as with the following example:

```
from random import randint
import numpy as np
dataframe = []
for i in range(2):
value = randint(0,10)
for j in range(2):
    mean = np.mean(value)
    dataframe.append(mean)
    cols=['mean']
    result=pd.DataFrame(dataframe, columns = cols)
result
```

This outputs a dataframe that looks like:

```
mean
8
8
9
9
```

How could I output a dataframe that looks like

```
mean_1 mean_2 mean_3 mean_4
8      8      9      9
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made the dataframe a pandas dataframe from the beginning. And then there are multiple ways to add an column. [Add Column](https://re-thought.com/how-to-add-new-columns-in-a-dataframe-in-pandas/#:%7E:text=%20How%20to%20add%20new%20columns%20to%20Pandas,methods%20that%20are%20cowered%20above%20can...%20More%20)

```
from random import randint
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame()
counter = 0

for i in range(2):
    value = randint(0,10)
    for j in range(2):
        counter += 1
        mean = np.mean(value)
        column_name = "mean_" + str(counter)
        df.loc[1, column_name] = mean
```

As Answer to the comment and I also moved the line where value is set. There it depends of course if you want the same number per column or everywhere a new number:

```
from random import randint
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame()

for i in range(2):    
    for j in range(2):
        value = randint(0,10)
        mean = np.mean(value)
        column_name = "mean_" + str(i + 1)
        df.loc[j + 1, column_name] = mean
```

Comment: If I wanted to have the 2 outputs from the first j in one column and the 2 outputs from the second j loop in another column, how could I do that?

Comment: So there would be two columns, mean_1 and mean_2

Comment: See added answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd
from random import randint
import numpy as np

m = 2
n = 2

dataframe = pd.DataFrame([0], columns = ['mean_1'])
for i in range(m):
    value = randint(0,10)
    for j in range(n):
        mean = np.mean(value)
        dataframe['mean_'+str(n*i+j+1)] = mean
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I tried to keep what wrote by adding few details: a counter for columns, and a assembling of your final dataframe. This is not the most optimised way but I mentionned tried to keep your logic.

```
from random import randint
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
dataframe = []
count = 1
cols = []
for i in range(2):
    value = randint(0,10)
    for j in range(2):
        mean = np.mean(value)
        dataframe.append(mean)
        cols.append('mean_'+str(count))
        count = count + 1
df=pd.DataFrame(columns=cols)
a_series = pd.Series(dataframe, index = cols)
d = df.append(a_series, ignore_index=True)
```

Output:
[image]