# Adding dataframe columns in nested for loop

Tags: python, numpy, for-loop

I recently asked this question: [Add new columns to a dataframe in for loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69822672/add-new-columns-to-a-dataframe-in-for-loop) but asked for the wrong thing.

I am able to write a for loop that adds a row to a dataframe each time as with the following example:

```
from random import randint
import numpy as np
dataframe = []
for i in range(2):
value = randint(0,10)
for j in range(2):
    mean = np.mean(value)
    dataframe.append(mean)
    cols=['mean']
    result=pd.DataFrame(dataframe, columns = cols)
result
```

This outputs a dataframe that looks like:

```
mean
8
8
9
9
```

I actually want all the values created from the j loop for each i to be in one column.  For example, if when i is 0, the two values outputted from the j loop are 2 and 5, and if when i is 1, the two values outputted from the j loop are 4 and 7 then my dataframe would be:

```
mean_1  mean_2
2       4
5       7
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use string formatting in your column names?
As you know the number of different values of i (in this case 2) you could predefine a dataframe and replace values as you go.
Something like:

```
from random import randint
import numpy as np

nrows = 2
df = pd.DataFrame(index=range(nrows))

for i in range(2):
    df['mean_%i'%i] = 0
    value = randint(0,10)
    for j in range(2):
        mean = np.mean(value)
        df['mean_%i'%i].iloc[j] = mean
```

Or something similar.